# How change information UILabel according to Tap on Google map marker ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps

I am working with [Google Map API for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/intro). When I tap on the `marker` I present a `view` which has `label` where I want to display data according to tap location. I want to change displayed data with tap but it is not working. Anyone, please help me with this who worked on google map ios SDK. Here is my code:

```
let tappedPosition = marker.position
        let tappedLatitude = tappedPosition.latitude

        let filteredBike = goBike.filter { $0.latitude == tappedLatitude }

        let filteredBikeMakeName: String = filteredBike[0].bikeMakeName

        let filteredBikeModelName: String = filteredBike[0].bikeModelName

        if filteredBike.count > 0 {
            goPullUpView.bikeModelLabel.text = "\(String(describing: filteredBikeMakeName)) \(String(describing: filteredBikeModelName))"
            goPullUpView.bikeNumberLabel.text = filteredBike[0].regNo
        }
```

Comment: you don't have to typeCast String value to String again. Label.text is always string

Comment: what do you mean with "not working"? Label is showing empty string? Label is showing incorrect string?

Answer (score 0):

```
func didTapMarker(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) {
        let tappedPosition = marker.position
        let tappedLatitude = tappedPosition.latitude

        let filteredBike = goBike.filter { $0.location?.latitude == tappedLatitude }

        if filteredBike.count > 0 {
          // Do something
        }

    }
```